# Associate all file extensions which a program can handle, with that program

Tags: windows-11, file-association

I have an audio program (lets say Foobar2000) which can play 100 type of audio files.

Is there a way in Windows 11, to reserve these 100 file extensions with Foobar2000 AT ONCE?

Because, on `Settings` -> `Defaults Apps` -> `<Specific App>` I must assign one by one the 100 file extensions to Foobar2000.

Ok. Now Foobar2000 is for audio extensions.

Media Player Classic is for video extensions.

XnView is for image extensions.

And there are lot of family users.

This is translated to a whole life of extension association.

Comment: There are 44 audio file extensions. This will take < 1 lifetime. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format

Comment: See [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280464/how-can-i-associate-a-file-type-with-a-powershell-script) post.

Comment: @spikey_richie Nice. What about all other users? I want to register the extensions for everyone. Also Foobar2000 is only one of 100000000000 programs in my PC.

Comment: I doubt you have 100 billion programs in your PC. If you had, and they were 1KB each, you'd need a 100 TB HDD.

Comment: @Destroy666 What I mean, is that: on Windows 11, even if a program (like Foobar2000) tries to associate e.g. 100 file extensions, Windows 11 silently REFUSE to associate them. But if you go to default programs and select Foobar2000 (it is on the list) you will see the extensions which Foobar2000 trying to associate UNASSOCIATED. Of course you can associate them ONE-BY-ONE with Foobar2000.

Comment: Ok, you edited your question to be more reasonable, so I retracted my vote.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no. Windows does not have such a capability. Yes the process for establishing file type associations is bad and has been getting worse and worse since Vista, and win11 is an all time low.

That said, keep in mind, a programmer can make a file of any given internal format and put any extension they want on it. File extensions are at best a convention. Only the developer of an application can tell what formats it supports, and what extensions are commonly associated with those formats.

As such it is the "responsibility" of the developer/packager to create those associations at install time. If they do not, all the user can do is to manually associate them.

Comment: As a personal note, I honestly think that MS is making the process for associating programs so poor so that they can push IE/Edge. On my work PC, I've had to reassociate this or that handler back to chrome at least 5 times in the last 6 months. they just released a "feature" to outlook that forces links in emails to open in edge regardless of association, and they'll be rolling it out to teams soon. so now not only do you need to reassociate types and handlers, you also need to change your outlook/teams settings....

Comment: even if a program has an installer, or has a button "Tell windows to reserve these extensions for me", these extensions must be selected one by one from the user and must be assigned to that program. The only easiness about that, is that the program already exists in the list of appropriate programs for every extension, if you press the above button.

Comment: also, after you associate your file extensions correctly, you must  set the permissions to read only, because Windows try to hijack your extensions.